# How to set display duration for Push Notification in javascript?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, notifications, service-worker

Here is the code of service worker that listens for the push notification:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
var payload = event.data ? event.data.text() : 'no payload';

event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification('Notify Message', {
            body: payload,
            icon: 'push.png'
        })   );

});
```

I have the push notification coming on my screen when a notification is sent. But i wanted to display the push notification on the screen for a certain time (for example say 90 seconds or some dynamic time duration which user who sends the notification would input). This is not for android or ios. This is desktop level notification. So, how to set the duration for the push notification?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Found solution to this?

Comment: No, not found .

Answer (score 1):

You can set requireInteraction parameter to  true for the notification to not get auto dismissed.
Currently there isnt a parameter for the duration.
you can check the documentation here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how you are displaying your notifications, could you implement a simple timeout, something along the lines of:

```
function clearNotice(notice) {
    // notice.hide();
}

function showNotice(notice) {
    notice.show();
    // clear your notice
    setTimeout(clearNotice(notice), notice.timeout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no listener available or property to set duration. You can close the notification using the below code

```
Notification.requestPermission(function(result) {
if (result === 'granted') {
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
    registration.showNotification('Notify Message', {
      body: payload,
      icon: 'push.png'
    }).then(function(event) {
         console.log(event);
          if(event && event.notification) {
            setTimeout(function(){ event.notification.close();}, 3000);
       }
  });
  });
}
```

});

Comment: I am getting TypeError: event is undefined in promise. But i am getting the notification.

Comment: give self.registration in above code and also check if (event.Notifcation) then close.